# How to construct a sequence that is the set of limit points but not equal to any element in another sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, constructive-mathematics

Let ${y_j}_{j=1}^N$ be N given real numbers. Construct a sequence ${a_n}$ so that ${y_j}_{j=1}^N$ is the set of limit points of ${a_n}$, but $a_n \ne y_j$ for any n or j.

My work is as follows, but it's probably wrong:
Suppose $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Zero is the only limit point, but $0 \notin a_n = \frac{1}{n} \forall n.$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, that's a good start but of course $0$ might not be one of your $y_j$.  Still, you can use your idea.  Suppose $a_n=y_1+\frac 1n$.  At least that gets us $y_1$ as a limit point (and none of the $a_n=y_1$). Now, can you generalize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you have $N$ **given** points so you can't just decide there is only one point which his zero. You need to work with the specific points that are given. I'll give a hint. Let $m=min\{|y_i-y_j|: 1\leq i<j\leq N\}$. Check that $m$ is well defined and is a positive number. So there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0}<m$. Of course it follows that $\frac{1}{n}<m$ for all $n\geq n_0$. So now use these facts and try to build a sequence.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Mark!